# How to find all class of member in symfony controller with findBy or with roles?

Tags: symfony

I can't get the classes of the member on the controller of member in symfony

i try with a query but i want to get all of the classes in function in controller of member!!
this the query:

```
  public function findAllLessons($user): array
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();

        $query = $entityManager->createQuery(
            'SELECT L
            FROM App\Entity\Lessen L
            WHERE L not in (SELECT L2 FROM App\Entity\Lessen L2 LEFT JOIN L2.registrations r WHERE :user = r.member)'
        );
        $query->setParameter('user', $user);

        // returns an array of Product objects
        return $query->getResult();
    }
```